# How can I find a table column and row in vue js?

Tags: c#, jquery, vue.js, model-view-controller, razor

These are the sample codes I've been using with el = "#app".

---

```html
<div id="app">
      <div id="customertable" style=" overflow:auto !important;height:100% ">
            <table class="table" id="table">
                <thead id="customerheadertable">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:1%"></th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Customer ID</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:30%">Customer Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:30%">Address</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Contact Number</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Actions</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="custtomerbodytable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td ref="customerid">(CUSTOMER ID)</td>
                        <td>(Name)</td>
                        <td>(Address)</td>
                        <td>(MOBILE NUMBER)</td>
                        <td>
                            <b-dropdown text="•••" class="activity_button">
                            <b-dropdown-item href="#" @@click="dropdown(event)" class="dropdown">View</b-dropdown-item>
                            </b-dropdown>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td ref="customerid">(CUSTOMER ID)</td>
                        <td>(Name)</td>
                        <td>(Address)</td>
                        <td>(MOBILE NUMBER)</td>
                        <td>
                            <b-dropdown text="•••" class="activity_button">
                            <b-dropdown-item href="#" @@click="dropdown(event)" class="dropdown">View</b-dropdown-item>
                            </b-dropdown>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
 </div>
```

---

How can I get the nearest value of ref="customerid" when clicking @@click="dropdown(event)"  using Vue JS.

### Like in jquery.

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
 $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').html().trim();
});
```

------[This is the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEdTX.png)

Comment: Would this inspire you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44617892/4636715

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined

Comment: Is your table data dynamically produced? If yes, you could just get the index of the click button on your function.